# canEqual in List returns true for Set argument

Tags: scala

**question 1 - Why does this code return true when I compare a List with Set (different elements) but returns false when I compare List with List or Set of?**

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val l2=List(1,2,3)
l2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val l3=List(1,3,3)
l3: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 3)

scala> l.canEqual(l2)
res2: Boolean = true

/*I guess this returns true becuase canEqual check for type of the passed instance. Something like def canEqual(other: Any): Boolean = other.isInstanceOf[List] */

scala> l.canEqual(l3)
res3: Boolean = true

//but if canEqual checks for type of passed instance then why this returns true when I call canEqual on List but pass a Set

scala> val s = Set(1,2,3)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.canEqual(s)
res4: Boolean = true

scala> val s2=Set(2,3,4)
s2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 3, 4)

scala> l.canEqual(s)
res5: Boolean = true

scala> l.canEqual(s2)
res6: Boolean = true
```

Probably canEqual in List doesn't check for instance List type but some superclass instance or probably doesnt override equals. Is this the case?

**Question 2 - I read that canEquals is used with equals and hashcode to define if an instance is equal to some other instance. canEquals is generally called by equals. Is there a usecase when a user will call canEqual directly from code (Like I am trying to do above)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with simpler example:

```
scala> "aaaa".canEqual(5)
res0: Boolean = true
```

So everything can be equal by default - but it doesn't mean that it will be. The real use case of `canEqual` is disabling equivalence (see [this article](http://marcus-christie.blogspot.com/2014/03/scala-object-equality-and-canequal.html)):

> canEqual method for non-final classes. This allows subclasses to
>   override canEqual if they want to not allow being equal to the parent
>   class or sibling classes.

So the whole reason of `canEqual` is inheritance (precicely disabling equality in siblings/parents). It is not recommended to call it outside of `equals` as it violates Liskov Substitution Principle as it stated in the article above.

IMHO, I would not recommended to use at all, it's counter-intuitive and [dangerous](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/8379). If you need to disable equality between entities it's better to prefer composition to inheritance, as inheritance logically requires inheritance of equality, but composition is more flexible.